# What kind of encryption does wallet use

Tags: wallet

What kind of encryption does wallet use?

Does its content get synced on remote storage?

Can I make a backup of my wallet?

Is there (somewhere) written by MS (in small or some other letters) that they can use or deliver my wallet content to some third party?

This faq written by MS doesn't really deliver,
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/apps/wallet-faq

Answer (score 2):

Going by the [developer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631258) Apps can only interact with items in the wallet "associated with that app", so I would interpret that as the Wallet is not accessible by third parties (as long as you don't consider the originator's app nor the built in Wallet app as third parties). It is also suggested that the on phone wallet is more of a statement of account, rather than the primary store of information, as wallets can synchronise over the air with the wallet item issuer (be that your bank, loyalty card scheme issuer, etc.).

It's unclear if the wallet is included in the phone backups, or if these are stored on the SIM card (you must have a "payment SIM", if you want to use tap-to-pay, which implies additional security/storage)

Comment: I'm not sure if the wallet is included in backups, but it is synced/saved somehow since I have several Lumias and my wallet syncs across all of them.